# Degree of the minimal polynomial of an algebraic number in genral

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Is there an (efficient) algorithm to find the degree of a minimal polynomial (over $\mathbb{Q}$) of an arbitrary algebraic number $\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is expresses in terms of some (complicated) radicals?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3554349/how-to-efficiently-compute-the-minimal-polynomial-of-a-number-expressed-in-radic